# RewriteRule with htaccess for custom PHP project

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to learn RewriteRule for htaccess on a small project.
It's my first time writing codes for htaccess.
So here's how the so-called project looks like (simplified):

```
root folder ___________ /admin/edit_order.php
                 |_____ /users/edit_order.php
                 |_____ index.php
                 |_____ sample.php
```

So, for this part I have used the following codes on my **.htaccess** file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC]
```

So, what I've learned so far is that the 2nd and 3rd lines are like **if** conditions and they consider if the path entered by user/used by the script is not a folder, and is a file. In such case it removes the **.php** extension and shows only the name.

So I have something like **abc.com/sample**. It also works for sub-folders (I have **abc.com/admin/edit_order**) So far so good.

But I have a problem with query strings or when I want to pass variables using the URL. Sometimes I may need to pass 1 variable, and sometimes 2 variables. So this is the code I wrote:

```
RewriteRule ^sample/([0-9]+) sample.php?id=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^sample/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) sample.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC]
```

I wrote the first line for when I only need to pass an ID, and the second line where I might also need to pass a name.
This also is the codes on **sample.php** and other PHP files (**edit_order.php** on both *admin* and *users* folders):

```
<?php
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $name=$_GET['name'];
?>
<html>
    <body>
        id: <?php echo $id; ?>
        <br>
        name: <?php echo $name; ?>
    </body
</html>
```

Now, the thing is when I pass only 1 variable (ID) it works just fine (what I enter is *abc.com/user/(any number)*). The script shows:

```
id: any_given_number
name: (prints nothing)
```

But even when I pass 2 variables, it shows the same result (what I enter is *abc.com/user/(any number)/(any name)*).

For the sub-folder, I added this piece of code:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/edit_order/([0-9]+) admin/edit_order.php?id=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^admin/edit_order/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) admin/edit_order.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC]
```

It also has the same outcome.

What I basically want, is to show only file names without their extensions either on root folder or sub-folders, and query strings without their default looks (something like **abc.com/sample/23/John**).
Also it would be perfect if I can write a code where I can use custom names for files, for instance, instead of **abc.com/admin/edit_order/34/Bag** I can get **abc.com/admin/EditOrder/34/Bag**.

I really appreciate some help on fixing this code.

Comment: I'm no expert on this, but I do the same thing my project. After each rewrite rule I add these flags `[L,NC,QSA,B]`. I forget what each one does, but you can lookup the documentation to find out more. Also, the order of your rewrite rules matters, so consider switching around the ordering if this does not work.

Comment: @JM-AGMS That actually did work! I changed the order of shorter and longer rules, and they started working as expected. Thanks for the suggestion. However there's still one thing I can not accomplish, which is using any desired name for files/sub-folders. For instance, instead of printing **abc.com/admin/edit_order** it prints **abc.com/admin/EditOrder**

Comment: Glad it helped. For your second problem try simply changing `^admin/edit_order/[...]` to `^admin/EditOrder/[...]` on both rules. If that does not work try disabling the `$1.php` rule.

Comment: @JM-AGMS I tried that. One weird thing happens. When I enter the path **abc.com/EditOrder** it ends up showing a 404 error, even-though that file/path exists. But when I enter **abc.com/EditOrder/(any_number)** or even **abc.com/EditOrder/(any_number)/(any_name)** it perfectly shows the content as it should.

Comment: Add a `?` after the`)` so it ends like this `[...]/([0-9]+)?`. The question mark makes the number optional. Right now a number has to match to make the rules work.

Comment: @JM-AGMS Unfortunately that didn't work.

Comment: Hmm. Try `[...]/([0-9]*)`.

Comment: @JM-AGMS That didn't work either. But I guess I'm fine with what I got at the moment. I'll try building my htaccess around what I learned so far. You helped a lot, thanks for that :)